# HTTP Status 404 | The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: mysql, eclipse, maven, jsp

i'm creating a maven project for a log in, log out, and registration form, im done with the codes but...after i run the project it always shows like this:

[after i run the project with no error this showed up at my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lkad.png)

[here's the problem window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e63uf.png)

how do i display my .jsp file from my eclipse to the browser?

i tried changing the server but the result is still the same, there's no error with the code, i think there's something wrong with the server setup

Comment: You don't appear to be a requesting a JSP file's URI. Why shouldn't you be getting a 404?